# Return product attribute object after creation

Tags: magento2.4, eav, setup-script, eav-attributes

I've made a class to create product attributes on the fly. After creating it I want to return it immediately. However `getAttributeByCode()` returns NULL. When I start another process the `getAttributeByCode()` will return the actual attribute object. What's my problem here?

```php
<?php

namespace Webwijs\FashionCloudProductEnricher\Attribute;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\AbstractAttribute;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Webwijs\FashionCloudProductEnricher\Api\Attribute\AttributeCreatorInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;

class AttributeCreator implements AttributeCreatorInterface
{

    private EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory;

    private ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup;

    private Config $eavConfig;

    /**
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param Config $eavConfig
     */
    public function __construct(
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        Config $eavConfig,
    ) {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->setup           = $setup;
        $this->eavConfig       = $eavConfig;
    }


    public function create( AttributeInfo $attributeInfo ): AbstractAttribute
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $this->setup->startSetup();
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create( [ 'setup' => $this->setup ] );
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            Product::ENTITY,
            $attributeInfo->getMagentoCode(),
            [
                'type'                    => 'text',
                'backend'                 => '',
                'frontend'                => '',
                'label'                   => $attributeInfo->getLabel(),
                'input'                   => 'text',
                'class'                   => '',
                'source'                  => '',
                'global'                  => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible'                 => true, //$attributeInfo->isVisible(),
                'required'                => false,
                'user_defined'            => false,
                'default'                 => '',
                'searchable'              => $attributeInfo->isSearchable(),
                'filterable'              => $attributeInfo->isFilterable(),
                'comparable'              => $attributeInfo->isComparable(),
                'visible_on_front'        => $attributeInfo->isVisibleOnFront(),
                'used_in_product_listing' => $attributeInfo->isUsedInProductListing(),
                'unique'                  => false, //$attributeInfo->isUnique(),
                'apply_to'                => 'configurable',
            ]
        );

        $attributeSetId = $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId( Product::ENTITY );
        $attributeGroupName = 'Fashion Cloud';

        $eavSetup->addAttributeToGroup(
            Product::ENTITY,
            $attributeSetId,
            $attributeGroupName, // attribute group
            $attributeInfo->getMagentoCode(), // attribute code
            10 // sort order
        );

        $this->setup->endSetup();

        return $this->getAttributeByCode( $attributeInfo->getMagentoCode() ); // NULL
    }

    public function getAttributeByCode( string $code ): ?AbstractAttribute
    {
        $attribute = @$this->eavConfig->getAttribute( Product::ENTITY, $code );
        if ( $attribute && $attribute->getAttributeId() !== null ) {
            return $attribute;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```